# String meant to store date in a table is converting an int for unknown reason

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, string, date

I'm trying to get the date to store as a string in a table, but the date keeps converting to a negative 4 digit number which correlates with the date, and I can't for the life of me figure out where I've messed up. Note that I'm using a combo of C# and SQL Server

```cs
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    int qty = 0;
    string pname = "";

    SqlCommand cmd3 = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd3.CommandText = "insert into order_item values('" + orderid.ToString() + "','" + dr["product"].ToString() + "'," +
        "'" + dr["price"].ToString() + "','" + dr["qty"].ToString() + "','"+ dr["total"].ToString() + "')";
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();

    qty = Convert.ToInt32(dr["qty"].ToString());
    pname = dr["product"].ToString();

    SqlCommand cmd6 = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd6.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd6.CommandText = "update stock set product_qty = product_qty - " + qty + " where product_name = '"+pname.ToString()+"'";
    cmd6.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // date keeps getting updated to negative 4 digit number which coordinates with the date. ex: 14-01-2020 is converting to -2007.
    SqlCommand cmd7 = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd7.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    **cmd7.CommandText = "update stock_over_time set product_qty = product_qty - " + qty + ", date_changed = " + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "" +
        " where product_name = '" + pname.ToString() + "'";**
    cmd7.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The reason is known - string concatenation. It exposes the code to SQL injection and conversion errors. Use proper parameterized queries instead

Comment: concatenating values into strings to make SQL is the first major problem; there is **no good** that can come from that  - (search: "SQL injection")

Comment: Better yet, google for `Bobby Tables`. Imagine what would happen if the `product` field contained the value `'; drop table Users;--`

Comment: Another serious conversion error, using `dd-MM-yyyy` as a date literal. That's a *localized* string and won't be recognized eg in the US, or result in the wrong dates, et April 7 instead of July 4. You won't have any such problems if you use a date-typed parameter

Comment: SQL Server has more than one DataTime type.  Check what the type is in the server.  It could be the date was stored incorrectly so when you use SQL Server Management Studio do a query of the database to verify the date are correct.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos about the famous Bobby table example, can you execute many query within a single `ExecuteNonQuery` ? I think connection string must allow batch

Comment: @Cid there's no such setting. Everything in the SQL query is one batch

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/disallow-batches/

Comment: @Cid that's a *My*SQL connection string. That's a weak protection against SQL injection because you can still inject eg `' OR 1=1` to get all rows in a table

Comment: Yep, I just noticed that question was about SQL Server, I was wondering if there were other DBMS that allow such settings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wasn't arguing about preventing SQL injections by disabling batch, parameterized queries are the way to go

Comment: @Cid I was reacting to the parameter's existence, although I suspect it exists for historical reasons, not as an injection prevention feature

Answer (score 5):

The *immediate* problem is that:

```cs
    , date_changed = " + date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + "
```

will become

```sql
    , date_changed = 15-01-2020
```

which is: `-2006`, which is (because of how dates are stored) some time in July 1894.

A **bad** fix for this would be to add quotes, but this is: **bad** - it has a range of problems to do with internationalization (is 08-01 the first of August? the 8th of January?), SQL injection, etc.

The **correct** fix is to use parameters throughout. For example:

```cs
cmd7.CommandText = @"
    update stock_over_time
    set    product_qty = product_qty - @qty,
           date_changed = @date
    where  product_name = @pname";
```

This, however, requires you to add parameters with the values.

The *simplest* way to do this would be with Dapper:

```cs
string pname = ...
int qty = ...
DateTime date = ...
con.Execute(@"
    update stock_over_time
    set    product_qty = product_qty - @qty,
           date_changed = @date
    where  product_name = @pname",
    new { pname, qty, date });
```

---

Note: **all** of your database access should be parameterized, either like the above, or using raw ADO.NET, or using tools like EF etc. Not just this one place; *everywhere*.

Answer (score 2):

A date should not be stored as a string datatype, instead change `date-changed` to a datetime type (or even just a date, since the values stored have no "time" element).

Also, it is advisable to use a parameterized query to avoid SQL injection

```
string sql = @"update stock_over_time set product_qty = product_qty - @qty, date_changed = @date where product_name = @pname";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString)
{
  connection.Open();
  using (SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
  {
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.SqlInt32).value = qty;  
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.SqlDateTime).value =  date;
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@pname", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = pname;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```